# Line tangent to circumference

Tags: geometry

Is true the following?
for any $r>0$, the line $r\left\{(x,y):Ax+By+C=0\right\}+(d_1,d_2)$ is tangent to circumference $r\left\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\right\}+(d_1,d_2)$ if and only if the line $\left\{(x,y):Ax+By+C=0\right\}$ is tangent to circumference $\left\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\right\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course!
The property of tangent doesn't change when it was translated. And It is obvious that the first pair of shapes intersects at single point if and only if the second pair intersects at single point.